# (WinSocket) Spam on Disconnect

Tags: c++, sockets, chat

I'm trying to write a server for a client/server chat program.
The only problem is that if once client disconnects, the server starts spamming their last message to the server. Even if they reconnect, it keeps spamming..I've tried googling, but I can't find anything. 
Here's the Server Code:

```
#include "MasterServer.h"
using namespace std;
SOCKADDR_IN Server;
int addrlen = sizeof(Server);
SOCKET sListen;
SOCKET Connect; 
SOCKET* Connections;
int port = 444;
int ConCounter = 0;
char* Recv = new char[256];
int ServerThread(int ID)
{

ZeroMemory(Recv, sizeof(Recv));
for(;;)
{
    if(recv(Connections[ID],Recv ,256 ,NULL))
    {
        cout << Recv << endl;
    }
}
}

int InitWinSock()
{
int RetVal = 0;
      WSAData wsa;
      WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2,1);
      RetVal = WSAStartup(Version, &wsa);

      return RetVal;
}


int main()
{
    int RetVal = 0;
    RetVal = InitWinSock();
    if(RetVal != 0)
    {
        cout << "WinSock Start Up Failure";
    }
      Connections = (SOCKET*)calloc(64, sizeof(SOCKET));

       sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
       Connect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
       cout << "\t\t----====ModernBacon Server====----"<< endl;

        cout << "What Port Would You Like To Run On [Default 444]: ";
        cin >> port;

        system("cls");
      Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
      Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
      Server.sin_port = htons(port);

      bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server));
      //Listening
      listen(sListen, 64);
cout << "Listening For Connections IP:"<<inet_ntoa(Server.sin_addr);"Port:"<<port<< 
endl;


      for(;;)
          {
            if(Connect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &addrlen))
            {
                Connections[ConCounter] = Connect;
                char* ID = new char[64];
                ZeroMemory(ID, sizeof(ID));
                itoa(ConCounter, ID, 10);
                send(Connections[ConCounter], ID, sizeof(ID),NULL);

                ConCounter = ConCounter + 1;
                CreateThread(NULL,NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) 
ServerThread, (LPVOID)(ConCounter -1), NULL, NULL);

                cout << "\t\tClient Connected!\tID: " <<
ConCounter << endl;



            }

      }
      return(0);
}
```

I have no clue whats going on...

Comment: Do you know what `recv` returns on error?

Comment: When a client disconnects the thread assigned to them never goes away. When a new client is assigned to that connection ID, then what happens? Also, all your threads share the *same* buffer for reading from the socket. That's another disaster.

Comment: Spamming is the act of sending junk email. There is no email code here. What on earth do you mean by 'spamming' in this context?

Comment: @EJP spamming was used in the correct context here. Spamming is to send the same message indiscriminately to (large numbers of recipients) on the Internet. He means the message gets resent over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with your code.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include "MasterServer.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static const int MAX_CLIENTS = 64;
static const int MAX_RECV = 256;

struct ClientInfo
{
    int ID;
    SOCKET Connection;
    char Recv[MAX_RECV];
};

ClientInfo Clients[MAX_CLIENTS];

DWORD WINAPI ServerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    ClientInfo *Client = (ClientInfo*) lpParam;
    char szID[64] = {0};

    itoa(Client->ID, szID, 10);

    int RetVal = send(Client->Connection, szID, sizeof(szID), NULL);
    if (RetVal != sizeof(szID))
    {
        cout << "Client " << Client->ID << " Send Failure. Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            RetVal = recv(Client->Connection, Client->Recv, MAX_RECV, NULL);
            if (RetVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Client " << Client->ID << " Recv Failure. Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (RetVal == 0)
            {
                cout << "Client " << Client->ID << " disconnected" << endl;
                break;
            }

            cout << "Client " << Client->ID << ": " << string(Client->Recv, RetVal) << endl;
        }
        while (true);
    }

    closesocket(Client->Connection);
    Client->Connection = INVALID_SOCKET;

    return 0;
}

int InitWinSock()
{
    WSAData wsa;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1), &wsa);
}

int main()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int addrlen;
    SOCKET sListen;
    SOCKET sClient;
    int port = 444;
    int index;

    cout << "\t\t----====ModernBacon Server====----"<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i)
        Connections[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;

    int RetVal = InitWinSock();
    if (RetVal != 0)
    {
        cout << "WinSock Start Up Failure. Error " << RetVal << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (sListen == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "WinSock Socket Failure. Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "What Port Would You Like To Run On [Default 444]: ";
    cin >> port;
    system("cls");

    ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    RetVal = bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (RetVal != 0)
    {
        cout << "WinSock Bind Failure. Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //Listening
    RetVal = listen(sListen, MAX_CLIENTS);
    if (RetVal != 0)
    {
        cout << "WinSock Listen Failure. Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Listening For Connections. IP: " << inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr) << ", Port: " << port << endl;

    do
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        sClient = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
        if (sClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << "WinSock Accept Failure. Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i)
        {
            if (Clients[i].Connection == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                 index = i;
                 break;
            }
        }

        if (index == -1)
        {
            closesocket(sClient);
            cout << "\t\tClient Connected. Max Clients Exceeded!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        Clients[index].ID = index + 1;
        Clients[index].Connection = sClient;

        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ServerThread, &Clients[index], NULL, NULL);

        cout << "\t\tClient Connected!\tID: " << Clients[index].ID << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```